# MVC Controller, testing a WCF service that is wrapped in a proxy

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to figure how to create tests for my controllers that are consuming a WCF service (via a proxy class)

The proxy class is pretty much identical to the one listed in this post http://blog.weminuche.net/2008/08/test-post.html

Base Controller

```
public abstract class ServiceProxyController<TService> : Controller
    where TService : class 
{

    private readonly ServiceProxy<TService> _proxyHelper;

    protected ServiceProxyController(string endpoint)
    {
        _proxyHelper = new ServiceProxy<TService>(endpoint);
    }

    private Stuff GetStuff(int num)
    {
         Call((service) =>  {
                    service.DoSomeStuff(num)
                 });
                ................
            }
     ...........
 }
```

Controller Implementation

```
public class MyController : ServiceProxyController<IService>
{
    public MyController() : base("ServiceBindingName")
    {
    }

     }
```

I want to be able to inject a proxy helper(???) into my controller so as I can mock it and therefor test the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about injecting the proxy helper to the constructor (notice the introduction of an abstraction):

```
private readonly IServiceProxy<TService> _proxyHelper;
protected ServiceProxyController(IServiceProxy<TService> proxyHelper)
{
    _proxyHelper = proxyHelper;
}
```

and the controller:

```
public MyController(IServiceProxy<TService> proxyHelper) 
    : base(proxyHelper)
{
}
```

This way in your unit test when instantiating the controller you could inject a mocked instance of the `IServiceProxy<TService>` interface.

You will then need to configure your DI framework to insert the proper implementation into the controller constructor which will wrap the actual `ChannelFactory`.

Comment: I think I get what your saying but the problem is that the ServiceProxy class' Call method uses the ChannelFactory to create a channel that is used when calling the delegate

Comment: @Dve, that's why you need to introduce an abstraction: `IServiceProxy<TService>` which will contain the necessary Call method. Then in the real implementation you could use the actual ChannelFactory and in the unit test you will simply mock this method.

Comment: But the delegate argument to the Call method will still need to be supplied and in turn will require a service to be passed to it

Comment: please note [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650804/rhinomocks-mocking-delegates/6672001#6672001) of how you can set expectations for delegates

Answer (score 0):

I just asked a similar question. I am injecting the service using structure map. I am dynamically creating a proxy using channel factory.

Look at this example for using Channel factory.

[creating WCF ChannelFactory<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200197/creating-wcf-channelfactoryt)

My question for your reference.

[Rhinomocks - Mocking delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650804/rhinomocks-mocking-delegates)

Note- Actually it was Darin who posted the ServiceInvoker